# How does one use CActiveRecord methods to update a db field to a function of itself without instantiating the model?

Tags: yii, query-builder

Say I have a model `Product` from a table with `id` and `in_stock` fields. I only require to update the the `in_stock` value to `(in_stock + added_stock)`. Is there a way to update it using the Yii functions without creating an instance of the model? I tried

```
Product::model()->updateByPk($id,array('in_stock'=>'in_stock+'.$added_stock));
```

but it didn't work.
Any solutions are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you intended that `$added_stock` is a local PHP variable? If so this is probably the best way:

```
Product::model()->updateCounters(
    array('in_stock' => $added_stock), 
    array('condition'=>'id = :id'),
    array(':id' => $id)

);
```

That should work to add an arbitrary amount to a field without querying the record. 
It will also cast the `$added_stock` variable into an integer before hand so there's no worry of SQL injection or need to place it in a parameter.

P.S works with decimals too. Although I don't think I want to know why you have to deal with fractions of units of stock ?? :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think my problem might be due to `in_stock` being a decimal field. The above query executes but resets the value to 0.0000 every time. Thoughts?

Comment: Not sure this will work how you want, even with the right syntax. The params array has to be passed as the 4th parameter of the method, and the 2nd parameter should be a an associative array of `'column_name'=>$new_value`. However, based on the behavior of other similar methods, the $new_value would be escaped and applied to the column as is. Likely it is trying trying to insert your command as a string into a decimal field.

Comment: Your right, that was completely wrong. I've updated with an answer that works. Have just tried it this time.

Comment: @Paystey It works! However, I had to change the second attribute to the string `'id= :id'` instead of using the array. And even better it also works for decrementing.

Comment: Good, glad it worked out. Strange about the `conditions` though, I used that code exactly to test before I posted. Could be differences in Yii versions I suppose, I'm on the bleeding edge. Nothing to worry about though, it should always be backwards compatible.

Comment: +1, good call, this problem is exactly what `updateCounters` was made for... glad I know about it now too!

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by others, I'm not sure why you can't create a model instance here and do it that way, but as you asked the question I guess you have a reason!

In that case, if you can't create a model and want to do it statically you could use [CDbExpression](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbExpression) to create the expression so that the whole of the expression won't be escaped by the query builder (which is what would have been happening in your example).

Something like this would work;

```
$added_stock = 1;
$newStock = new CDbExpression('(`in_stock`+:addedStock)',array(
    ':addedStock' => $added_stock)
);
Product::model()->updateByPk($id,array(
    'in_stock' => $newStock
));
```

The above code would increment `in_stock` by whatever the value of `$added_stock` is.

Comment: The method I was looking for was the `updateCounters()` below. However, your answer is brilliant for a non-counter field. Thanks. You've been +1'd.

Comment: Why did I not know about `CDbExpression`? I could've saved my self countless headaches. Oh well, live and learn....

Comment: no probs @Paystey & @topher...  I hadn't heard of `updateCounters` before, so we all learnt something new!! :) CDbExpression is great for inserting values such as `NOW()` into a table (among many other things!)

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not quite sure why you want to avoid creating an instance of the model, you can do it this way:

```
$sql = "SELECT in_stock FROM Product t WHERE id=:id";
$params = array(':id'=>$id);
$in_stock = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql)->queryScalar($params);

Product::model()->updateByPk($id, array(
  'is_stock'=>$added_stock+$in_stock,
);
```

Of course, it seems a lot more work that way. You can always wrap that in your own static method inside the Product model and call it that way.

```
public static function addStock($id,$added_stock){
  (place code from above here)
}
```

Can you elaborate on why you don't want to create an instance of the model?

Comment: I had thought of this but I wanted to avoid the first `SELECT`. I have records in different tables that are being updated when a certain model is saved. Only the first record needs validation.